# Command line float input and output using streams

Tags: c++, stream, command-line-arguments

My first question on this site, here goes:

I am working on a tutorial question and it asks me to write a program that outputs the product of some entered floating point numbers from the command line: This is to be done using streams.
Now in My tutorial book it suggests using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

int main(  int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{  

          float data[20];
          int i;
          float sum;

          for(i=1;i<argc-1;i++){

              istream cinx(81,argv[i];

              cinx>>data[i];
              cout<<data[i];

              sum=sum+data[i];
         }
         cout<<"\nsum = "<<sum;
}
```

So I have tried the above code and many different variations until my hair is falling out! - But to no avail as it does not compile, instead I get the error message along the lines of:

" no matching function for call to `std::basic_istream >::get(char**&, int)"

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, put down the tutorial and buy [a proper book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

istream constructor expects a streambuf. You probably want to use istringstream:

```
istringstream cinx(argv[i]);
```

and `#include <sstream>` in the beginning.

Besides, you're computing the sum, not the product.

Comment: Many Thanks for Helping outybungalobill 
I tried your suggestion and the code compiled successfully.
Very helpful, but I did not understand want you meant: "You're computing the sum not the product" - Are they not the same?

Comment: @user993858: A sum is the result of addition.  The product is the result from multiplication.

Comment: Yes of course - I feel a bit dumb not knowing that in the first place!(which I did but just kind of forgot!) So I guess what you are implying is that istringstream is more suited to the sum not the product of some float numbers?

Comment: Yes I see my other mistake - in the opening question above I say I am wanting to compute the product but really I am wanting to compute the sum, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Helping outybungalobill and Paul R.

The final code which compiled and runs successfully is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(  int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{  

          float data[20];
          int i;
          float sum = 0.0f;

          for(i=1;i<argc;i++){


              istringstream cinx(argv[i]);

              cinx>>data[i];
              cout<<data[i];

              sum=sum+data[i];
         }
         cout<<"\nsum = "<<sum<<"\n";

   system ("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The proper way to thank people on this site is to upvote and accept their answers.

Comment: Hope you are happy now dude, tried to give you an up vote but need higher reputation! - So anyway I accepted your answer you are now elevated to supreme position. Is there anything else I can do for you- -Clean your boots perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing parenthesis. Change this line:

```
          istream cinx(81,argv[i];
```

to this:

```
          istream cinx(81,argv[i]);
```

Also you need to initialise `sum` - change:

```
      float sum;
```

to:

```
      float sum = 0.0f;
```

And you're also off by one on the number of command line arguments - change:

```
      for(i=1;i<argc-1;i++){
```

to:

```
      for(i=1;i<argc;i++){
```

Comment: The code has compiled sussecfully using your corrections and the use of istringstream with #included <sstream>.